# Paisaje de siempre

Tags: uso-de-palabras

I read a line the other day in Almudi.org that said

> Mi paisaje de siempre visto desde otra perspectiva

the latter part means 'seen from another perspective'. I can't quite figure out what could be a good english equivalent of the former. My landscape of always? That doesn't make english sense. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Spanish.SE. Thanks for the interesting question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would translate it by:

> My everyday landscape, seen from another perspective,

or

> My usual landscape, seen from another perspective.

Comment: +1 "de siempre" works as an adjective here. Other alternatives  "cotidian", "ordinary", "familiar"